# Dark Hex color by string php

Tags: php

I want to generate a dark hex background color by a string name in php? 
The hex color must be the same for the same string, I tried by using hash:

```
 $backgrounColor = substr(md5('blabla')), 0, 6);
 $fontColor = 'fff';
```

Comment: And does it work? I suppose it doesn't or you wouldn't be here. What's your actual question/problem?

Comment: Although what md5 returns contains “hex-save digits” (0-9, a-f) only, there is _of course_ no guarantee whatsoever that any arbitrary combination of those characters actually result in a _dark_ color.

Comment: so what is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say a 'dark color' you mean a color where all channels are under a specific intensity you could do something like this:

```
function hashColor($srcString) {
    $maxItensity = 0x80;

    $hash  = crc32($srcString);
    $red   = ($hash & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
    $green = ($hash & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
    $blue  = ($hash & 0x0000FF);

    $red -= ($red > $maxItensity) ? 0xFF - $maxItensity : 0;
    $green -= ($green > $maxItensity) ? 0xFF - $maxItensity : 0;
    $blue -= ($blue > $maxItensity) ? 0xFF - $maxItensity : 0;

    $color = ($red << 16) + ($green << 8) + ($blue);

    return "#" . str_pad(dechex($color), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```